# How can i create a folder inside a bucket

Tags: supabase

I am currently trying to create a folder inside a bucket already created with a migration, but I have not found any command that will allow me. I have only found commands to create rls or create buckets with `supabase`. The only doc that i found is for create the bucket but not the folder inside

for example: `avatars/image_avatar`

```
-- Use Postgres to create a bucket.

insert into storage.buckets
  (id, name)
values
  ('avatars', 'avatars');
```

Comment: Folders are automatically created when you try to place a file under a certain folder, so you don't need to explicitly create them.

Comment: Hello thanks!, but i got a question. If i add a new table in locally then run the supabase db reset, that bucket may be deleted in the process? like when i run db reset without having a migration with inserts

Comment: Storage file and bucket information is just rows in your storage.objects and storage.buckets tables. You can add those rows in your seed.sql file to have them auto populate on db reset!